# Ansible : Add an ip with docker_network?

Tags: docker, networking, ansible

Is it possible or is there a solution to add a network to an already existing docker container ?

Here is the solution I found for the moment:

```yaml
- name: Add network
  docker_network:
    name: network_nextcloud
    connected:
      - openldap_app
    appends: yes
  when: OPENLDAP_MAP_WITH_NEXTCLOUD == "yes"
```

The above solution works but I would like if possible to set an ip to it without going through the `docker_container` module.

Do you have any solution(s)?

- I have read the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/docker_network_module.html
- Did several tests with docker_network and docker_container

Comment: It seems like you've already found a working solution, and using the Ansible Docker integration seems like the right approach; what problem are you running into?  (Why don't you want to use the `docker_container` module?)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

In fact I ask via vars_prompt if it was necessary to intergrate the container in a new network.

```yaml
- name: Docker install OpenLDAP
  connection: local
  hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: OPENLDAP_MAP_WITH_NEXTCLOUD 
      prompt: Do you want map with Nextcloud (yes/no)
      private: no
      defaults: "{{ OPENLDAP_MAP_WITH_NEXTCLOUD }}" # Defined in <ROLE>/defaults/main.yml
  roles:
    - docker_install_openldap
```

In reality if we use the command : `docker network connect --ip ...` in manual with ansible the module to use is not `docker_network` but **`docker_container`**...

I attach below the piece of code that worked for me:

```yaml
- name: Add network
  docker_container:
    name: openldap_app
    networks:
      - name: network_nextcloud
        ipv4_address: "{{ NEXTCLOUD_IP_OPENLDAP }}"
        aliases:
          - openldap_aapp
    appends: yes
  when: OPENLDAP_MAP_WITH_NEXTCLOUD == "yes"
```

Thanking you ! @david-maze

Comment: Hi, why to thank an user, without upvoting his answer? Do that! Upvote useful content, this helps others to quickly find solutions

Comment: Hi @pierpy, thank you for your comment, it's my first one and it allows me to learn how to use stackoverflow, but I don't think I can upvote my own post. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I was on my phone, I didn't see you auto-replied to your qestion! There are so many users thanking, but not upvoting or accepting the correct answer :)